# IndexError: list index out of range: When try to display digits into English words

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to learning programming and I tried to make a simple prg to display input digits into English upto 999, it works correctly till 99 but when it comes to 100's than i get following error:
please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

```
print('Print digits into english upto 999')
words_upto_ninteen=['','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Eleven','Tweleve','Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen', 'Sixteen','Seventeen','Eighteen','Nineteen']

words_tens=['','','Twenty','Thirty','Fourty','Fifty','Sixty','Seventy','Eighty','Ninty']

words_hundreds=[' ','One Hundred','Two Hundred','Three Hundred','Four Hundred','Five Hundred','Six Hundred','Seven Hundred','Eight Hundred','Nine Hundred']

n=int(input("Please enter digits 0 to 999:"))
output=''
if n==0:
    output='zero'
elif n<=19:
    output=words_upto_ninteen[n]
elif n<=99:
    output=words_tens[n//10]+"  "+ words_upto_ninteen[n%10]
elif n<=999:
    output=words_hundreds[n//100]+" "+ words_tens[n//10]+" "+ words_upto_ninteen[n%10]

else:
    output=print('Please enter value upto 999')
print(output)
print('###########################################################################################')
```

Sample Output:

```
Please enter digits 0 to 999:433
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python learning/projects/4flow control/rough2.py", line 21, in <module>
    output=words_hundreds[n//100]+" "+ words_tens[n//10]+" "+ words_upto_ninteen[n%10]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `433//10` is `43` which is `> len(words_tens)`

Comment: What is `443//10`? Do any of your lists have that many items? Here's some complimentary debugging tips https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution would work:

```
print('Print digits into english upto 999')
words_upto_ninteen=['','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Eleven','Tweleve','Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen', 'Sixteen','Seventeen','Eighteen','Nineteen']

words_tens=['','','Twenty','Thirty','Fourty','Fifty','Sixty','Seventy','Eighty','Ninty']

words_hundreds=[' ','One Hundred','Two Hundred','Three Hundred','Four Hundred','Five Hundred','Six Hundred','Seven Hundred','Eight Hundred','Nine Hundred']

n=int(input("Please enter digits 0 to 999:"))
output=''
if n==0:
    output='zero'
elif n<=19:
    output=words_upto_ninteen[n]
elif n<=99:
    output=words_tens[n//10]+"  "+ words_upto_ninteen[n%10]
elif n<=999:
    output=words_hundreds[n//100]+" "+ words_tens[(n//10)%10]+" "+ words_upto_ninteen[n%10]

else:
    output=print('Please enter value upto 999')
print(output)
print('###########################################################################################')
```

You made a mistake in `words_ten[n//10]` in fourth condition. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you Sir for the answer, I really helps and I really missed the modulus operator, now it clears...

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

When the error IndexOutOfRange is encountered, an array field is accessed which does not exist. If the number 100 is reached, the case elif n <= 999: is reached for the first time. We have n = 100, we also have 
output = words_hundreds [100 // 100] + "" + words_tens [100 // 10] + "" + words_upto_ninteen [100% 10] 
and thus 
output = words_hundreds [1] + "" + words_tens [10] + "" + words_upto_ninteen [0]. However, the words_tens array will count to the words_tens [9] field, since 0 starts counting.

Comment: Thank you Sir for explaining, It was really helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: please give a positive rating by clicking on the upper triangle next to my text. Thank you very much